# Cannot connect to SQL Server Instance anymore after enabling UFW on Ubuntu 16.04 with webmin already installed

Tags: sql-server, apache, webmin, ufw

I enabled UFW on a ubuntu server setup by someone else following the documentation on digitalocean. This server already had virtualmin/webmin installed.

Enabling the UFW had no effect on traffic with only OpenSSH allowed, and defaults set to incoming (deny), outgoing (allow). I was still able to visit the website even when Apache as not added to the UFW rule.

I had to reboot the server to see if the UFW will kick in, but the status of the firewall was "inactive" and now I cannot connect to the SQL Server Instance via the application or SSMS even after disabling the firewall.

The application has been down for hours, the world is on my neck and am almost at the end of my rope.

Comment: I *assume* SQL Server is running on your Ubuntu Box? If not, `ufw` has nothing to do with this. If it is on the Ubuntu Server, and `ufw` is inactive, then it won't be stopping you connecting; which implies the (SQL Server) service isn't running. You can find out using `sudo service mssql-server status`.

Comment: `ufw` won't stop local connection either. If Webmin and SQL Server are running on the same host, `ufw` won't stop the connections; it'll only stop those coming from external IPs that aren't in the allowed list (or have an explicit `DENY`).

Comment: Thanks @Larnu running the command showed that sql server was  was active... but I can't seem to connect to it...

Comment: From where are you trying to connect to it, from the localhost, externally? Have you tried connecting using `sqlcmd` from the localhost? if the connection fails, what error do you get? if it works, clearly there is a firewall issue.

Comment: I am trying to connect to it both via the application (website) and remotely using SSMS... I tried connecting locally with  sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P 'xxxxxxxx' and it presented the following errors : 
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Client unable to establish connection.

Comment: You haven't recently updated to the latest CU per chance, have you? If so, what version of `msodbcsql17` do you have installed?

Comment: I can also see that port 1433 is not open could that be a factor?

Comment: *"I can also see that port 1433 is not open could that be a factor?"* On `ufw`? Only for connection not from the localhost.

Comment: I did run apt-get upgrade on my server

Comment: *"I did run apt-get upgrade on my server"* prior to this happening?

Comment: yes prior to this happening...

Comment: What are values for `installed` when you run `sudo apt-cache policy msodbcsql17 mssql-server`?

Comment: *"yes prior to this happening..."* Well, that's some **really** important information we've been missing for the last hour... Sounds like youn have the old odbc drivers installed still.

Comment: Any idea how i can update the drivers without affecting the data?

Answer (score 1):

Going on guesswork here after multiple comments.

Sounds like you have updated the version of `mssql-server` but haven't updated the `msodbcsql17` package. The latest CU needs the latest version of `msodbcsql17` (unsure why, but not having it installed causes the connection failures).

Firstly update your packages:

```
sudo apt update
```

Then install the latest version of `msodbcsql17`:

sudo apt install msodbcsql17

This *should* install version 17.4.2.1-1.

If this, for some reason fails. You could roll back the update to `mssql-server`:

```
sudo apt install mssql-server=14.0.3223.3-15
```

Comment: I had to setup a new sql server database to test this to be sure I wont loose any data... turns out rolling back to a previous version fixed the connection issue though in my case i rolled back to 14.0.3192.2-2, thanks for this.... I couldn't  have done this without you.